# Hydration problem with client-side authentication and computed property in Vue/Nuxt layout

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, hydration

My app (vue/nuxt 3) stores the user authentication state in localStorage. As a consequence it is only available on the client and prerendered pages always show the unauthenticated content.  Client will render the authenticated content as soon as it is aware of it. That's ok and accepted.

However, this does not seem to apply for computed properties. My whole layout depends on the authentication state, e.g. like this:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="computedClasses">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const computedClasses = computed(() => ({ 
  if ($someReferenceToStore.user.logged.in) {
    return 'loggedin'
  } else {
    return 'anonymous'
  }
}))
</script>
```

The problem is, that even though the user is logged in, the `computedClasses` is not updated to `loggedin` but the server generated `anonymous` is shown. How to solve this? How can I make the client update the computed property and overwrite the server rendered classes?

I know, I can wrap parts of my template that depend on the authentication state with `<ClientOnly>` to avoid hydration mismatches. Wrapping my layout with `<ClientOnly>` would basically disable any server rendering. Can I set a property of an element (the `:class="..."`) to client-only?

Comment: If it's specific to a user, it should not be SSR'ed anyway. Using `client-only` will only not SSR the code nested inside of it, not the whole app. Also, I think that a DOM mismatch is not taking into consideration the CSS (could maybe try to verify that one firstly). As always, if you want to debug this kind of issue I recommend toggling JS back and forth to see what are the differences between server/client. Overall, if it's specific to a user, it should not be generated on the server: your facebook feed is not SSR'ed, it's kept only on the client since it's a personalised/dynamic content.

Comment: The layout is not really user-specific. But it depends on whether the user is logged in or not. I want to SSR the "not logged in" layout. The layout is the outer-most div. So, if I put `client-only` around it, my whole app will be in it...

Comment: If it depends if logged-in or not, it's what I call specific. You can always refractor your code to allow the skeleton to be public (SSR'ed) but otherwise I'm not sure what to say. If the type of your app asks for an authentication early (like Facebook), you're pretty much down with SSR, mainly because some layout doesn't really bring any benefit SSR-wise.

Comment: No, my app is pretty much usable without authentication. But if you are authenticated you can use more functionality that is in a separate menu bar. Whether this menu is displayed or not, is part of my layout... To simplify: I need to change properties (like width) of the main `div` (with all the content that should be SSRed) depending on the authentication state. How would you refactor that? Sorry, might be a stupid question, but I have no idea...

Comment: You could refactor it to be 80% SSR'ed and 20% client only. No secret sauce here but the reconciliation during the hydration is not THAT flexible in Nuxt. Some frameworks like Qwik/Marko may offer more granularity but the overall concept of hydration is quite clunky. Still, if you don't use most of the benefits, SSR is not worth it for 100% of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to use a ref that's being updated.

```html
<template>
  <div :class="computedClasses">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const computedClasses = ref('');

onMounted(() => {
  computedClasses.value = $someReferenceToStore.user.logged.in ? 'loggedin' : 'anonymous';
});
</script>
```

Depending on the use case, one might want to add a watcher to update the ref as well.